# How do I convert/ build .juce file to vst3 plugin

Tags: vst, juce

The [following](https://github.com/lukemcraig/negative-harmonizer-plugin) repository contains a .juce file along with c++ source file. The operating system I am currently working on is Ubuntu. I want to be able to build this file into a .vst3 file so that it can be added as a plugin in any DAW which has that capability. When I open the .juce file in Projucer, it only lists Visual Studio 2017 as an exporter option, with no option to add exporters (usually for Linux, the options are Code::Blocks and Makefile). How do I build the source files here to create a .vst3 plugin file?

Answer (score 1):

In the projucer application, if you click on the plus icon in the bottom left, you will get a menu with which you can specify which exporter configuration you want to add to the project.

After adding the linux makefile as an exporter configuration, you should save the projucer file which will generate the makefiles.

Then you can use "make" via terminal to compile the plugin in the specified formats.

Please make sure to enable the VST3 option in the settings page.

[image: Screen shot of the mentioned menu in Ubuntu]